# Embedded RavenDB - how to run management studio on a different port

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

It currently runs on 8080, but I need that port for another service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
                        {
                            Configuration =
                                {
                                    Port = 12345,
                                }
                        };
```